partial feedback linearization with observation
I am considering a partial feedback linearization system with relative degree 2.
I have to stabilize a state $x_1$, during estimating $x_2$.
Can I describe it below? and recommendation for book and paper?
$\dot{x}=f(x)+g(x)u$ $x$ is states with $x=[x1;x2]$ and $u$ is input.
$x1$ states is observing and $x2$ is not observable.
The relative degree is two.
$Au+L_f=\mu$.
Let us stabilize with partial feedback linearization $h_1=x_1$.
And $\eta=\begin{bmatrix}h_1 \\ \dot{h_1} \\ h_2 \\ \dot{h_2}\end{bmatrix}$
Let us reduce error $h_2=\hat{x_2}-x_2$
$\dot{eta}=F\eta + G\mu$
$F=\begin{bmatrix}0&1 \\ 0&0 \\ 0&1 \end{bmatrix}$
$G=\begin{bmatrix}0 \\ 1\end{bmatrix}$
After that, use this matrix to calculate the Lyapunov candidate.
